# Remotely execute SSIS package multiple times simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an ASP.NET app where I want to execute an SSIS package multiple times simultaneously (the package may take awhile to execute, and I will want the ability to kick off another instance before the first one finishes). The web server is not on the same server as SQL Server, and does not have SQL Server or SSIS installed.

I can execute SSIS by wrapping it around a SQL job and using `sp_start_job`, but since a SQL job cannot run twice simultaneously, this won't work for me.

[From what I understand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355(v=sql.105).aspx), .NET cannot start SSIS directly without having a special installation on the client, which I won't have. And I'm not in a position where I can install a special remoting handler on the SQL server.

Any idea how to do this given these restrictions? I've got plenty of other workarounds that I can explore, but I'd like to use SSIS if I can.

SQL Server 2008R2 and .NET 4.5

**EDIT**

I've found some solutions using `xp_cmdshell`, which I don't think will fly since that seems like a security issue - or by creating a job on the fly, executing it, then dropping it, but the user account won't have permission to create a job on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same SQL Agent job running more than once, so why not cheat?

Instead of calling [`sp_start_job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx), what if you called [`sp_add_job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx), [`sp_add_job_step`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx) and then invoked `sp_start_job`

Since I've specified delete_level = 1, the job will delete itself after successful execution.

Given the following job definition, append a GUID or something similar to the end of `IAmUnique` and boom, unique job name and you can run them concurrently.

```
DECLARE @jobId binary(16)
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'IAmUnique'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_netsend = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @owner_login_name = N'EU\u001899'
,   @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'IAmUnique'
,   @step_name = N'Run package'
,   @step_id = 1
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 1
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'SSIS'
,   @command = N'/SQL "\New Package" /SERVER "localhost\dev2008" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E'
,   @database_name = N'master'
,   @flags = 0;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
    @job_name = N'IAmUnique'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @start_step_id = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 2
,   @notify_level_netsend = 2
,   @notify_level_page = 2
,   @delete_level = 1
,   @description = N''
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @notify_email_operator_name = N''
,   @notify_netsend_operator_name = N''
,   @notify_page_operator_name = N'';
```

Comment: I wasn't going to consider this option since the user would need rights to create jobs, which I assumed would make it way too powerful and wouldn't be a good security policty. But as I look into the permissions, it looks like we can grant the account the lowest agent permission - [SQLAgentUserRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) - without giving it a bunch of permissions that it shouldn't have. I'll dig a little deeper into this to see if this works.

Comment: @JoeEnos You could further restrict by creating a stored procedure which is able to create and run the job and only granting the application the ability to execute that proc which is then using something like `Execute AS` to perform actions at a higher privilege level. I figured if you're letting the app execute jobs, probably wasn't a bigger concern about letting it create them.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to start the package from a stored procedure. Specifically, I'd look at the [catalog.create_execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878034.aspx) method. Then just call the stored procedure from ASP.NET.

The following MSDN documentation may help: [Deploy and Execute SSIS Packages using Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx)

**Edit:** The above only works for SQL Server 2012 and newer. For older, you'll likely need to run the SSIS package from the command line, using DTExec, which could be achieved through a stored procedure as well.

See the following: [Executing a SSIS Package from Stored Procedure in SQL Server](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/executing-a-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: Looks like that's new in SQL2012, so it's a no-go for me. But it definitely looks like the right way in 2012+. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeEnos You're right, I overlooked that. You'll probably need to run DTExec from the command line, through a stored procedure. See my update above for an example.